# Unobtrusive JavaScript with jQuery in MVC 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Let say somewhere in MVC 3 application I have

```
if (Model.ImageListGallery != null)
{
    <h3>@ImagesTranslation.Gallery</h3>

    foreach (var imageInGallery in Model.ImageListGallery)
    {
        <div id="@imageInGallery.IdImage">
            <a rel="group" href= "@Url.Action("displaybig", "news", new { idNews = Model.IdNews, idImage = imageInGallery.IdImage })">
                <img src= "@Url.Action("displaysmall", "news", new { idNews = Model.IdNews, idImage = imageInGallery.IdImage })" alt=""/></a>
            @Html.Label(ImagesTranslation.Description)
            @Html.TextArea("Description", imageInGallery.Description, new { id = "area" + imageInGallery.IdImage, onfocus = "removeDisabledBtnOnImage('" + imageInGallery.IdImage + "')" })
            <button disabled="disabled" id="btn@(imageInGallery.IdImage)" onclick="saveDescription('@imageInGallery.IdImage')">@CommonTranslations.Save</button>
            <img class="@imageInGallery.IdImage" src="@Href("~/Content/delete.png")" onclick="deleteImage('@imageInGallery.IdImage')" title="@ImagesTranslation.DeleteImage" alt=""/>
        </div>
    }
}
```

How would you use unobtrusive JavaScript with jQuery in that situation (event onfocus and onclick?

Comment: I mean there is a value in that kind of programming in mvc 3. And as I see web development is trying to avoid using html events in that kind of way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding a class to the parent div, you can identify each of the gallery images as something that needs to have handlers added to its elements:

```
foreach (var imageInGallery in Model.ImageListGallery)
{
    <div id="@imageInGallery.IdImage" class="gallery-image">
        <a rel="group" href= "@Url.Action(...)">
            <img src= "@Url.Action(..." alt=""/></a>
        @Html.Label(ImagesTranslation.Description)
        @Html.TextArea("Description", imageInGallery.Description, new { id = "area" + imageInGallery.IdImage })
        <button disabled="disabled" id="btn@(imageInGallery.IdImage)">@CommonTranslations.Save</button>
        <img class="@imageInGallery.IdImage" src="@Href("~/Content/delete.png")" title="@ImagesTranslation.DeleteImage" alt=""/>
    </div>
}
```

```
$(function() {
    $('.gallery-image').each(function() {
        var t = $(this);
        var imageId = t.attr('id');
        t.find('textarea').onfocus(function() {
            removeDisabledBtnOnImage(imageId);
        });
        t.find('btn').onclick(function(){
            saveDescription(imageId);
        });
        t.find('img').onclick(function(){
            deleteImage(imageId);
        });
    });
});
```

There are other ways to go about it, but hopefully that gives you the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of data attributes (new in HTML5) to pass data to your javascript.

So I would change your view code to something like:

```
if (Model.ImageListGallery != null)
{
    <h3>@ImagesTranslation.Gallery</h3>

    foreach (var imageInGallery in Model.ImageListGallery)
    {
        <div id="image_@imageInGallery.IdImage" class="editable-image" data-image-id="@imageInGallery.IdImage">
            <a rel="group" href= "@Url.Action("displaybig", "news", new { idNews = Model.IdNews, idImage = imageInGallery.IdImage })">
                <img src= "@Url.Action("displaysmall", "news", new { idNews = Model.IdNews, idImage = imageInGallery.IdImage })" alt=""/></a>
            @Html.Label(ImagesTranslation.Description)
            @Html.TextArea("Description", imageInGallery.Description, new { id = "area" + imageInGallery.IdImage })
            <button disabled="disabled" id="btn@(imageInGallery.IdImage)" >@CommonTranslations.Save</button>
            <img class="delete-image" src="@Href("~/Content/delete.png")" title="@ImagesTranslation.DeleteImage" alt=""/>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Javascript (jQuery)

```
$(function() { 
   $('.editable-image').each(index,elem) {

      elem = $(elem);
      var id = elem.attr('data-image-id');      
      var delete = elem.find('.delete-image');
      var save = elem.find('button');
      var area = elem.find('textarea');

      delete.click(function() { deleteImage(id) });
      //etc..
   }
});
```

Comment: I like your answer better, but could you fix the 'var id=...' line?

Comment: Ok. Tnx guys. I appreciate it. Generally I know advantages of unobtrusive JS, but isn't the old way faster in terms of page execution? Or is this actually irrelevant question

Comment: @TheMentor: If you have all your CSS and javascript in static, cacheable files, there shouldn't be much difference in terms of page execution. You're reducing the size of the HTML in the page somewhat (which could make things faster), while at the same time causing jQuery to do some additional processing as the page loads (which could make things slower). However, both of those effects are minimal and will most likely never be noticed by your users.